# How to exclude files from Eclipse's clean command

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want to exclude files from being removed by Eclipse's Project Clean. I'm working on an SDL application and I therefore need to have the SDL.dll file present in the Debug folder.

Is it possible to exclude for example *.dll files from being removed by the clean operation? If so, how do I do that? I don't have a makefile present in my Eclipse CDT project so I can't just edit the clean goal.

Answer (score 3):

Put the dll into a source folder, it will be copied automatically in the target folder

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will clean all files in your output folder on a save.  If you don't want the dll files removed, then you must move them from the output folder.  From the way that you describe your problem, it seems like you need these files to be on the debug path of your project.  I'm not entirely sure how to set this up in CDT, but there is probably a way of adding this in your project's properties (right click -> properties).

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the file in the clean section of an Ant script, then import the script into Eclipse as a new project.